# Adjusting margins for points in margin with xsim

Tags: spacing, geometry, xsim

With `xsim`, how can you adjust the space between the exercise and the number of points, using the default style?

If I change the horizontal margins manually for my document (using `geometry`), then the number of points is actually outside the printing area, how can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1in}
\begin{document}
    \begin{exercise}[points = {10}]
        Write.
    \end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Note that the number of points etc are typeset inside a `\marginpar`, so the `\marginparsep` has to be wide enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default style is defined like this:

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{default}{%
  \subsection*
    {%
      \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
      \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
      \IfInsideSolutionF
        {%
          \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
            { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
        }%
    }
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}
    {%
      \marginpar
        {%
          \IfInsideSolutionF{\rule{1.2cm}{1pt}\slash}%
          \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
          \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~(+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})}%
          ~\XSIMtranslate {point-abbr}%
        }%
    }%
}
{}
```

As you can see the exercise title is typeset as a `\subsection*`. If points are given they are typeset with a `\marginpar`. This means the position of the points is controlled by the dimensions of the document (textwidth, marginparsep, …). IMHO your problem rather is that `\rule{1.2cm}{1pt}` is too wide for your margin or that the points are written behind instead of below the rule.

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  hmargin = 1in ,
  showframe
}

\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom
}


\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
  \subsection*
    {%
      \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
      \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
      \IfInsideSolutionF
        {%
          \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
            { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
        }%
    }
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}
    {%
      \marginpar
        {%
          \IfInsideSolutionF{\rule{1.2cm}{1pt}/\\}% <<<< NEW
          \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
          \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~(+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})}%
          ~\XSIMtranslate {point-abbr}%
        }%
    }%
}
{}



\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[points = 10]
  Write.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "that the points are written behind instead of below the rule": yes, that's excellent, thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for.